# cqlsh OperationTimedOut when connecting

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh

We have a Cassandra server that ran out of disk space, after that we upgraded the disk space.

But since then it has not been possible to connect with cqlsh.

I am trying to connect to cassandra locally on the server but i just get the following error.

It seems like it just uses the default connect timeout of 5 seconds and ignores my connect-timeout parameter..
Any ideas what could be wrong?

```
python cqlsh 10.0.12.10 --connect-timeout 3600 --debug
Using CQL driver: <module 'cassandra' from '/usr/share/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip/cassandra-driver-3.0.0-6af642d/cassandra/__init__.py'>
Using connect timeout: 3600 seconds
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'10.0.12.10': 
OperationTimedOut('errors=None, last_host=None',)})
```

Comment: Any errors in Cassandra logs on startup? Most likely it isn't running or isn't binding to 10.0.12.10. `netstat -an | grep 9042` will tell you if it is bound to any interfaces

Comment: it ran out of disk space and I would imagine that system.log will tell you it's unable to start cassandra for that reason even if there is new space available.